# setOnClickListener from external file for fullscreen activity

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have a VideoPlayerActivity to play videos in exoPlayer, and i was adding `FullScreen` option with `setOnClickListener` and i was able make video player to play in full screen.

here is the code:

```
boolean fullscreen = false;

 imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(fullscreen) {
                    imageView1.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(VideoPlayerActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_open));
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
                        getSupportActionBar().show();
                    }
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) playerView.getLayoutParams();
                    params.width = params.MATCH_PARENT;
                    params.height = params.MATCH_PARENT;
                    playerView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    fullscreen = false;
                }else{
                    imageView1.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(VideoPlayerActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_close));
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
                    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
                        getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    }
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) playerView.getLayoutParams();
                    params.width = params.MATCH_PARENT;
                    params.height = params.MATCH_PARENT;
                    playerView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    fullscreen = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

now my problem is how do i make a separate class file for full screen with above code, something like `FullScreenActitvity.java`and added above code to work from `VideoPlayerActivity.java` with onclick.

Comment: You want a fullscreen video to play in a separate activity, or you just want your code to be written in a separate class, e.g. to tidy your code?

Comment: @codebod the second option, written in SEPARATE CLASS FILE.

Comment: You just need a static method with signature `static boolean newMethod(ImageView iv, View playerView, Context ctx, boolean fullscreen)` by the looks of it. Change `View` to whatever type of thing a `playerView` is. Method should return the new fullscreen value. `ctx` will give you access to the methods you need that require an Activity context.

Comment: @codebod i want to access the above code from separate file with onClick, how do i do that

Comment: Write the method I've described in a new class, e.g. `FullScreen.java` and call it in `onClick` with `fullscreen = FullScreen.newMethod(imageView1, playerView, VideoPlayerActivity.this, fullscreen);`.

Comment: @codebod can you show how it can be done.

Comment: You have all of the code needed, I've told you how to call the new method, so all you need to do is move your code from your `onClick` method to the new method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you need static method with that code:

```
imageView1.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(VideoPlayerActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_open));
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
    getSupportActionBar().show();
}
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) playerView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = params.MATCH_PARENT;
params.height = params.MATCH_PARENT;
playerView.setLayoutParams(params);
fullscreen = false;
```

So, here is your final code:

FullScreenActitvity.java

```
static boolean method(ImageView imageView1, View playerView, Context context) {
    imageView1.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_open));
    ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
        ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
    ((Activity) context).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) playerView.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = params.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = params.MATCH_PARENT;
    playerView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return false;
}


imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(fullscreen) {
            fullscreen = FullScreenActitvity.method(imageView1, playerView, VideoPlayerActivity.this);
        }else{
            imageView1.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(VideoPlayerActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_close));
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
            if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
            }
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) playerView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = params.MATCH_PARENT;
            params.height = params.MATCH_PARENT;
            playerView.setLayoutParams(params);
            fullscreen = true;
        }
    }
});
```